Large string into array, but with a twist! (PowerShell)
So, I have a single large string that looks something like:
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line

And so forth. I've converted this into an array, but you might see the issue based on the information above.
The array now looks like:
$array[0]
Date, Status, Data

$array[1]
More Data about above line

I would like to take every two lines in the large string and make that a single entry into the array, so it looks like:
$array[0]
Date, Status, Data
More Data about the above line

Is there a simple way to do this?
This is the code I'm using to split it up from a large string to array:
$in = "your text"
$lines = $in.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | ? { $_ -ne "" }

The above examples explain pretty well what I'm seeing. I'm able to tear the large string apart and stuff it into an array, but the output is less than ideal, because I want every two lines in the large string grouped into a single array entry.

Please also add to your question the code you're using to get this string

I'd do a regex split with a lookahead for your date format. There could be issues in cases where line 2 starts with the same date format, but if it's not too much data you could loop through things and look for items that don't have a new line character in them, and merge that with the next record and that should resolve that.


The regex-based -split operator enables a concise solution:Tip of the hat to Santiago Squarzon for help with the regex.
$in = @'
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line1
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line2
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line3
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line4
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line5
'@ 

$array = 
  $in -split '(?m)(?<=\G^.+\n.+)\r?\n'


For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see this regex101.com page; in short, it uses a positive lookbehind assertion to match two consecutive (non-empty) lines, and splits by the subsequent newline.


Just to not get rusty myself, here's an alternative approach to complement the other answers, using the less commonly used $foreach variable inside a foreach statement.
$array = @'
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line1
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line2
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line3
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line4
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line5
'@  -split "\r?\n"

$new_array = foreach ($line in $array) {
    $previous = $line
    $null = $foreach.MoveNext()
    @($previous, $foreach.Current) -join "`n"
} 

By saving the current iteration $line to $previous before calling on .MoveNext(), as the method name may imply, we can join it with the next iteration by referencing $foreach.Current and passing both lines to our -join operator.

Not sure this has any value over mklement0's answer, but it is a less intense regex version.  All the regex does is split the string into lines, and the rest of the code joins every pair of lines.
Assuming you have this:
$in = @'
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
'@

You can do this:
$Lines = $in -split '\r?\n' | & {
   begin {
      $Tog = $false;$Tmp = ''  # Define variables
   }
   process {
      if ($Tog = -not $Tog) {  # Toggle tog and check tog
         $Tmp = $_             # Odd lines are saved
      }
      else {
         "$Tmp`r`n" + $_       # Return even lines appended to last odd line
      }
   }
   end {
      if ($Tog) {$Tmp}         # If last line was odd, return it
   }
}

And removing the spaces, you can condense it to a single long line:
$Lines = $in -split '\r?\n'|&{begin{$Tog=$false;$Tmp=''}process{if($Tog=-not$Tog){$Tmp=$_}else{"$Tmp`r`n"+$_}}end{if($Tog){$Tmp}}}


StringBuilder assigned to $tmp would be an improvement of this approach as it would save a ton of memory. A normal loop would also improve it if there is no need for streaming.

@SantiagoSquarzon, good point, especially if $in was very large.

This one is kind of thanks to Santiago's comment on using StringBuilder, which in general is a very good idea.  But when I decided to try using it with this problem, I really did NOT like what I was coming up with!  For one thing, to make the results efficient in a large input string, you probably also need to use a list to hold the ever expanding array.
Scrapping the idea of using StringBuilder, and rethinking the problem to it's most basic actions, we get:

Search for "`n" and move to next location.

Take advantage of the fact that even in a CRLF pair, LF is last.
Take advantage of .IndexOf() returning -1 when it fails.
Take advantage of the fact that the next line starts 1 place after new line.
Take advantage of the fact that -1 + 1 = 0.
Take advantage of the fact that 0 is considered $false by if


Search for "`n" again, and move to next location.

Take all the same advantages given in step 1 above.
Also, take advantage of the fact that the start of the next line, minus the start of this line, is the length .Substring() wants.


If index is NOT 0, then return copy of what we found.

NOTE: You may have to do some extra work if having strings ending with CRLF is a problem.


If index is 0, return rest of the line and break out of while loop.
If still in while loop, then keep going until we are past end of string.

We now have a function Split-LinePairs based on the above:
- $i - index
- $l - length of input string
- $s - start of line
function Split-LinePairs {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
      [string]$String
   )
   process {
      $i = 0                                          # Create an index variable set to the start of the string.
      $l = $String.Length                             # In some languages, reading length once is a good idea - may have no value in PowerShell.
      while ($i -lt $l) {                             # Quit when $i is past end of string.
         $s = $i                                      # Save start of string for later use.
         if ($i = $String.IndexOf("`n", $i) + 1) {    # Find the position after next `n, or move to 0 if fails and 0 is false so exit IF.
            if ($i = $String.IndexOf("`n", $i) + 1) { # Find the position after next `n again, or move to 0 if fails and 0 is false so exit IF.
               $String.Substring($s, $i - $s)         # Return our string starting at $s and with the length of $i - $s.
            }
         }
         if (-not $i) {                               # Check if the above code set $i to 0, and if so,
            $String.Substring($s)                     # return rest of string,
            break                                     # and exit while loop.
         }
      }
   }
}

Again, assuming you have this:
$in = @'
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line
'@

And you can use it in this way:
$Lines = $in | Split-LinePairs


Lets not forget about the boring old for loop.
$in = @'
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line1
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line2
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line3
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line4
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line5
'@ -split "`n"

$lines = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $in.Count; $i = $i + 2) {
  $in[$i], $in[$i + 1] -join "`n"
}


Here is another using pipeline and ForEach-Object (variation to Abraham's great answer using pipeline instead)
$lines = $in | ForEach-Object -Begin { $previous = $null } -Process {
  if ($null -eq $previous) {
    $previous = $_
  } 
  else {
    $previous, $_ -join "`n"
    $previous = $null
  }
} 

Note: This version however will not work if there is an odd number of lines.  The last line will be not be outputted.

After you get $array from @mklement0's answer, you might want something to create an array of records.
$Records = @()
foreach ($Item in $array) {
    if ($Item -match '^(?<Date>.*),\s*(?<Status>.*),\s*(?<Data>.*)\r\n(?<MoreData>.*)$') {
        $Records += [pscustomobject]@{
            Date = $Matches.Date
            Status = $Matches.Status
            Data = $Matches.Data
            MoreData = $Matches.MoreData
        }
    }
}

An example execution:
PS C:\src\t> .\ml.ps1

Date Status Data MoreData
---- ------ ---- --------
Date Status Data More Data about above line1
Date Status Data More Data about above line2
Date Status Data More Data about above line3
Date Status Data More Data about above line4
Date Status Data More Data about above line5


try avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection as it is inefficiënt (especially for a large inputs where it gets more expensive with each iteration).

My two cents on top of the already given helpful answers:
Think positive
The -split operator that by default splits based on a regular expression often invites to a negative approach, meaning trying to define everything that doesn't match as apposed to the positive approach where you trying to define everything that does match what you need.
For this, you might simply use the [regex]::Matches method:
$array = [regex]::Matches($in, '(?<![\S ])[\S ]*\r?\n[\S ]*').Value

Explanation:

[\S ] are all non-white-space (\S) characters and a normal space.
(White-space characters include: carriage-return, linefeed, form-feed etc.)
(?<![\S ]) look behind: the actual pattern should not be proceeded by a non-white-space character (except for a normal space)
[\S ]*\r?\n[\S ]* a string which contains only one newline.

The PowerShell way
+1 for darin's One-at-a-time processing answer. Where Stackoverflow generally pushes for a minimal reproducible example it also says Don't just skip straight to the code!. Especally for PowerShell it is often important to get some background on the end-to-end goal. As for this issue, the concerned "large string into array" needs to be loaded into memory somehow with could be taken as a part of your final solution where you might ask yourself whether you could just stream it using the sophisticated PowerShell Pipeline. Knowing that this will safe memory and could even perform better (as you might immediately start processing and do not have to wait till everything is loaded in memory).
Assuming that you data comes from a file, you might use the Get-Content cmdlet:
Get-Content .\in.txt | ForEach-Object { $Last = $Null } {
    if ($Null -ne $Last) {
        ,@($Last, $_)
        $Last = $Null
    } else { $Last = $_ } 
} # | % { "Spanned: $_" }

(Note that not just the filesystem but also a lot of other data sources might allow you to stream your data.)
Output
Your output "make that a single entry into the array" is somewhat ambiguous.

It could mean that the single entry is a string of two lines separated by a newline:

$Entry = @'
Date, Status, Data
More Data about above line1
'@ 


or that the single entry a (sub)array existing out of two strings:

$Entry = @(
    'Date, Status, Data',
    'More Data about above line1'
)

Note here that the output of both $Entry objects look the same when displayed.
Although I suspect that you expect the first $Entry type, I used the later (sub)array type in the above ForEach-Object example as it is easier to manipulatie. The downside is that it might lead to some confusion as the default output of the above example might look the same as the input (when the # | % { "Spanned: $_" } is left commented out) but if you remove the comment-hash you will see that the lines are indeed paired:
Spanned: Date, Status, Data More Data about above line1
Spanned: Date, Status, Data More Data about above line2
Spanned: Date, Status, Data More Data about above line3
Spanned: Date, Status, Data More Data about above line4
Spanned: Date, Status, Data More Data about above line5

A well defined Pipeline (as ForEach-Object) is implemented for the middle of a pipeline where at the end it either passed on to the next cmdlet, displayed or stored somewhere (and eventually released from memory).
In you case, this would mean that you might consider to join the sub-array with a comma (,) and write it to an output file, e.g.:
... | ForEach-Object { $_ -Join ', ' } | Set-Content .\Out.txt

All streamed with a minimum of memory usage.
